# nav menu with jquery is not working in IE7,fadin and fadout

Tags: jquery, menu, navigation, fadein, nav

```
(function () {
    var $make = $('li.prod');
    $('div.models').addClass('hide');
    $make.on('mouseenter', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.next().fadeIn(150);
    });
    $make.on('mouseleave', function () {
        var $that = $(this);
        $that.next().fadeOut(150);
    });
})();
```

This is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EmpKrauser/hwEdV/9/). I am wondering why my code does not work well in IE7. Also, how do you make the submenu open when hovering your mouse on it. Any help or suggestions will be much appreciated. I'm still a noob when it comes to jquery.

Comment: I think you should try the same thing with only html and css3 instead of jquery . May be this link can help you in http://sitepop.wordpress.com/2012/06/02/css-horizontal-multilevel-menus/ Thanks

Comment: @rahularyansharma CSS3 would definitely not work in IE7. PS: your fiddle works in my IE7

Comment: your html is invalid - you shouldn't have divs within the ul, they should be in the li

Comment: Thanks Rahul. I'll bookmark and read that link. @BASarat I wonder why it does not work on my version of IE7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By moving the `<div>` for submenus inside the `<li>`, the latter will remain open when you hover your mouse on the items of the submenus.

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/hwEdV/12/

EDIT: Jsfiddle is throwing script errors all over the place for IE7-8 so, i'm unable to test it for IE7

Answer (score 0):

I saw your script and it is fine but problem is that.next() does not support in IE7.